# Single Supply in Op-amps

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I am using in a project **TL081** operational amplifiers and an **INA118P** instrumentation amplifier.
Both need a **± 15 V Symmetric Power Supply**, however I have seen some projects in which it uses **single supply**.

I intend to build a portable system that sends electrical signals to the body (sinusoidal voltage of  2 V pp with 100 kHz to 1 mA). And for this I will use the op amps TL081 to make a high pass filter, a current source and a voltage follower. With the INA118P I will amplify the signal.

***My questions:***

I'm going to use arduino, I intend to use a **single 5 V supply** and GND.
*What's the difference between a Symmetric Power Supply and Single Supply?*

*The TL081 does not have much information about Single Supply Operation. For the voltage that I intend to work, is 5 V enough?*

Thanks!

Comment: No, 5 V is not enough, the minimum recommended is +/-5 V (or 10 V if you dynamically split a single supply. since you only need 2 V p-p, it would be possible to use a single 5 V power supply, but you need to select different devices.

Comment: What does the datasheet say the minimum recommended power supply rails are?

Comment: Okay, For the TL081, 5V single supply is not enough. But for INA118 it's allowed, right?
I found the AD8606, I looked at the datasheet, and it allows 5V single supply, besides it, does anyone know another device that allows 5V single supply?

Comment: Just google `single supply low voltage opamp`  The INA118 datasheet says: `The INA118 can be used on single power supplies of 2.7 V to 36 V` Remember sometimes need a "ground" plane at 2.5 V is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the datasheet. The absolute maximums don't list a minimum supply voltage, but there recommended operating conditions.
[image]
+/-5V minimum is a 10V single supply, not out of the ordinary for a JFET op amp.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between a Symmetric Power Supply and Single Supply?

None, absolutely none. the opamp will never know if the dual supply is symmetrical or not - and many times it is not; nor does it care if it is powered by a dual-rail supply or a single-rail supply.

> The TL081 does not have much information about Single Supply Operation.

it is right there in the datasheet, for maximum Vcc+ - Vcc-. As the opamp isn't spec'd for single rail operations (due to its limited common mode voltage range).

> For the voltage that I intend to work, is 5 V enough?

depending on the application. it cannot get too close to the rails - 1.5 - 2v headroom is needed typically. So at 5v, your "usable" range of output is quite limited.

Comment: I beg to clarify something: although it is true the opamp doesn't know and/or care if the supply is a dual symmetric or a single supply, opamps can be *specifically branded as "single-supply"*, and it actually means something *very* significant: it means their negative supply voltage is included in their common-mode input range (and, therefore, if the negative supply is gnd - which is the case for a single supply - you can still use gnd as a valid input voltage - which is forbidden for a regular opamp, whose common-mode input range typically starts a few volts away from both rails).

Answer (score 1):

In single-supply operation "ground" can't be the negative rail. TL081 (and in general all op-amps for symmetric supply) need a minimun of negative supply (not necesarilly the same symmetrical value, but at least -5 or -6 volts). I repeat: Ground CAN'T be the negative rail.